# How to create custom Action in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am new to cocos2dx and I want to make my own custom action like `MoveTo` or `MoveBy`.

Please help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried, where did you get stuck?

Comment: I am just beginner and now only using predefined Actions of cocos2d-x. Actions of cocos2d-x is quite smooth but when i move sprite from one position to other, it's having not such feel so I think I need to implement own Action for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cocos2d-x having number of Actions like `MoveTo/By`, `RotateTo/By`, `ScaleTo/By`, `FadeIn/Out`, `TintTo/TintBy`....

Furthermore you can create complex Actions by sequencing two or more actions by `Sequnce` Action.

If you need own implementation create child of `ActionInterval` and implement your own requirement.

An interval action is an action that takes place within a certain period of time. It has an start time, and a finish time. The finish time is the parameter duration plus the start time.